# Is it possible to set path of database for delayed job in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Now, I am developing with mailing system with delayed_jobs gem.
When I ran on developing environment, it operated well.
But, after deploying application on server, it is not acted.

This is my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3 
  database: /var/www/service/shared/db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I checked queue(in /var/www/service/shared/db/production.sqlite3) and it act well. Also, I started delayed_jobs(rake jobs:work).
So, I think that problem is delayed_job crawl db/development.sqlite3

How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rake jobs:work will work only for development environment.

For Production:

Install daemons gem.

```
 gem 'daemons'
```

then run

to start program

```
 /script/delayed_job -e production start
```

to stop program

```
 /script/delayed_job -e production stop
```

Rails 4: replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job

Out delayed_job file should look like

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

 require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
 require 'delayed/command'
 Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

Comment: Thank you, pooja. Now, I checked delayed_job is worked(using database). But, I get other problems that attempts is fail. And I got a error message(BLOB (Size: ...) / last_error cols). What mean is it?

Comment: Job Class#notification_email (id=156) FAILED (2 prior attempts) with NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for #<Array:0x00000004d61c68>// This is error on log. I don't know when it call 'merge'. Also I do not have 'merge' function..